# uninstall ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: 12.04, lts

How can I uninstall ubuntu 12.04 LTS from my laptop and start again the installation from the scratch, i.e. by making the partition and soon staff.
I made re-installation yesterday and ended up with a mess in the boot. The dual boot option is not available anymore. I made a boot repair and still couldn't get out of this problem. If it helps to give some advise, please, have a look to the link below for the boot information

http://paste.ubuntu.com/1350363/

one more question: Is it possible to delete some of the partitions that I have? if so, please let me know so that I will install ubuntu only in my laptop in one partion.
Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If needed, use a liveCD and open the Disk Utility or GParted to remove or reformat partitions.
You should be able to do this during installation as well.

Your boot options are likely due to the dual boot with windows. Make sure you've assigned the boot partition to be managed by windows or it will ignore one or the other.

http://www.dedoimedo.com/computers/dual-boot-windows-7-ubuntu.html

Pay special attention to the part about configuring the bootloader.